# Are There Any Important Differences Between These Two Code Approaches?

Tags: elixir

I've got some Elixir code on which I was working with some colleagues.  The very simplified code below should demonstrate the essence of the question I'm trying to resolve.

```
defmodule DemonstrateQuestion do
   def fh(), do: :unknown
   def fh("A"), do: :a
   def fh("B"), do: :b
   def fh(_), do: :unknown
end

defmodule AlternateBehavior do
   def fh(_\\nil)
   def fh("A"), do: :a
   def fh("B"), do: :b
   def fh(_), do: :unknown
end
```

I prefer the approach in `DemonstrateQuestion` because it explicitly calls out the zero arity function head.  But I cannot detect any functional difference between `DemonstrateQuestion` and `AlternateBehavior`.  So my question is, is there a valid technical reason (e. g. calling out the zero arity function head helps Elixir to generate better byte code) to prefer one approach or the other?

Comment: The AlternateBehavior is much more readable and flexible in my opinion, just because the compiler defines zero arity function in case of default parameter doesn't mean you have to do it manually.

Comment: I definitely agree there's some readability and clarity issues on both approaches; I was trying to put the decision on a more technical footing--hence my question.

Comment: this is done at compile time, so it doesn't matter very much on performance impact, since at runtime it will be the same. For the sake of experiment you can try to create 2 modules, compile them and inspect the .beam files to see if there is any difference.

Comment: *The AlternateBehavior is much more readable...*--I disagree, The function head with the default parameter could just as well have been written: `def fh(_\\:forty_horses)`, which I find confusing.  What is the meaning of the default value?? In addition, I have to look down several lines of code to figure out what the return value is for the call `fh()`.  *...and flexible*--How so?  *just because the compiler defines zero arity function in case of default parameter doesn't mean you have to do it manually* -- Explicit is always clearer than implicit.

Comment: But, because `fh/0` is a completely different function than `fh/1`, I would separate them by a blank line.

Comment: Don't know the answer to the question, but there's also `def fh(), do: fh(nil)
`

Comment: These are all good points and in fact someone over on the slack suggested pretty much the same thing @Daniel.  Decompiling them does show a difference so I guess it would depend on how important the difference is, given context.  In my context it's neglible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can get the erlang code back out of BEAM file if `Code.compiler_options(debug_info: true)` has been set (fwiw, in the `iex` session it’s set by default.)

First, we need to compile the input to BEAMs. The simplest way would be to create the projects with `mix new`, create `config/config.exs` with the single line `Code.compiler_options(debug_info: true)`, and compile the project.

Then run `iex` and do the following magic:

```elixir
{:ok, {_, [{:abstract_code, {_, dq}}]}} =
  :beam_lib.chunks(
    '_build/dev/lib/PROJECT_NAME/ebin/Elixir.DemonstrateQuestion.beam',
    [:abstract_code])
dq_code = :erl_prettypr.format(:erl_syntax.form_list(dq))
dq_code |> to_string() |> IO.puts()
```

You’ll get back the erlang source. Notice

```erlang
-export(['__info__'/1, fh/0, fh/1]).

...

fh() -> unknown.

fh(<<"A">>) -> a;
fh(<<"B">>) -> b;
fh(_) -> unknown.
```

For the alternate case it’d give back

```erlang
fh() -> fh(nil).

fh(<<"A">>) -> a;
fh(<<"B">>) -> b;
fh(_) -> unknown.
```

---

That said, the alternate approach gives a neglectable subtle overhead for `fh/0`: a superfluous function call `fh(nil)` instead of the direct return of `:unknown`.

Comment: it makes sense, since in the first case the code is duplicated not run through pattern match.

Comment: @Daniel clearly, I also could point out to the [tag:elixir] code to show how the default head clause is expanded, but the question was about a proof and there is no better proof than comparing BEAMs.

Comment: A well-written and well-reasoned answer.  Thanks!